# User-specific information in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, swig

I'm in the middle of writing a Python frontend to a large library written in C.  The users of my code will need to have already downloaded `libhuge.a` and its header files. Or they will have downloaded the source and compiled it themselves.  I have no way of knowing where these files exist on their computer.  Some users may not have root access to their machines.

My setup.py builds a SWIG interface, compiles the generated C `huge_wrap.c` code using the header files, and then builds the .so by linking against `libhuge.a`.

I realize that I could set an environment variable and use this to populate my `include_dirs` and `library_dirs`.  But I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

My eventual goal is to make this code pip installable.

Comment: In the past I've done this by running `pkg-config` from my `setup.py` file to find suitable compiler and linker parameters. These days I include `libhuge.so` in a "binary wheel" so users don't have to compile anything.

Comment: @JimEasterbrook.  Can binary wheels deal with needing a separate libhuge.so for Mac and Linux, and a third libhuge.dll for Windows?  The thought of 3 OS's and 4 versions of Python (2.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10) each needing their own .so scares me a little bit.

Comment: Yes, the wheels are Python version and OS specific. I use GitHub Actions to compile for multiple versions.
I was wrong when I said I "used to use `pkg-config`" - I still do as you need a source package for any machines you don't provide wheels for. I include the SWIG output files so people don't have to install SWIG though.
It can all get rather messy, as in this example: https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-exiv2/blob/main/setup.py